# Can elements be styled with external CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

An external CSS file is applied globally to the referencing HTML page. Is it possible to limit the scope.

I am aware that I can do `.myCssClass` etc but for this project, I'm going to need 2 very different styles in one page. Consider 2 divs, where one uses CSS stylesheet 1 and the other uses stylesheet 2 (and there will also be the orthodox CSS for the site).

The style sheets will also be used else where, so I can't edit the CSS. It would be idea to share the external CSS by element. Something like

```
<div stylesheet="../style.css">content 1</div>

<div stylesheet="../style2.css">content 2</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Basically... **NO**. You'd need to be specific in your selectors. There is no "only use this stylesheet" option in HTML/CSS

Comment: If you can edit the HTML (which it appears you can by your example), why don't you change the selector for `div` 2?

Comment: @Paulie_D can you move to an answer please?

Comment: Build the specificity of your selectors to target particular areas of your page. eg. `.myContainer .myInnerDiv .someOtherElement` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scoped` attribute, but unfortunately it is supported only by Firefox. So, the `id`s and `classes` is the best, accepted, approved and common solution.

```
<div>
  <style scoped>
    h1 {color:red;}
    p {color:blue;} 
  </style>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>hello world! I'm of blue color!</p>
</div>
<p>I'm out of the scope, so I'm of the black color :(</p>
```

Comment: Sorry how do you defined `scoped`?

Comment: Scoped is obsolete?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-style-element.html#attr-style-scoped

Comment: as I said, any browser except Firefox implemented that, so I'd rather avoid using that

Answer (score 0):

You must have then 2 different classes for them, one class from style.css and other from style2.css, as they'll overwrite one over the other if you only use the '*div*' selector, if you can choose a specific class from each style.css, I think that would be wiser than complicating your life, or try the solution that Paweł posted

Answer (score 0):

As far I know isn't possibile, but you can create "zones" using CSS selectors, in example, take a look here:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="myElement">
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<div class="myElement"></div>
</div>
```

with this selector in css:

```
.content .myElement{
height:50px;
width:50px;
background-color:blue;
}
```

only the div with "myElement" class wrapped in the div with the "content" class will be affected by this rule.
here's a fiddle showing this case:
https://jsfiddle.net/fn7ohw75/